# Reflection to create an assembly of a given type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm attempting to get a class type from a string.  I feel I may be going the long way about this, but this is the code I have so far:

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyFunc");

string myInterfaceId = "ITest";
Type myType = _type;  // This is a WPF App that ultimately calls this process
                      // Debugger shows that _is correctly populated

AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName(myType.AssemblyQualifiedName);  // Error here
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(an);

System.Reflection.MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(
                a.GetType(myInterfaceId))
```

The error I get is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

So, I have the assembly already in memory at the point that it errors.  Is it not possible to use reflection to load an assembly already in memory?  Is there a way to use reflection t load this without using `Assembly.Load(...`?

EDIT:

Thanks to @stakx suggestion, I finally came up with this:

```
var meInterfaceType = myType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Name == myInterfaceId)
```

Comment: We can see your code that does not work. But what do you actually want to do? Why do you want to load that assembly? What are you going to do with it? That would be important to know since, as you're saying, you might be taking a detour already, and ideally we would help you reach your goal on the easiest way, not with getting you going on the detour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your project is not referencing the assembly containing `ITest`, the easiest way to get a `Type` object equivalent to `typeof(ITest)` might be via the [static `Type.GetType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx):

```
// you need to specify the assembly-qualified name of your type parameter type:
var t = Type.GetType("FooNamespace.ITest, FooAssembly, Version=…, PublicKeyToken=…");
```

(If you are referencing that assembly in your project, simply set `t = typeof(FooNamespace.ITest)`.)

Then proceed with closing your generic method:

```
var openMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyFunc"); // as before
var closedMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t);
```

Comment: Thanks - while this didn't directly solve my problem, it did put my on the right path (see edits for the final solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type like this:

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyString");
```

Then use activator to get your instance:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) is the most fool proof string, but if your class is in the executing assembly, namespace.ClassName will work fine.

```
var type = Type.GetType("AssemblyQualifiedNameOfTheClass or namespace.ClassName");
var thing = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

From this point, you can use the "thing" just like you would use an instance of "namespace.ClassName".